# Timing time it takes for user to answer a raw_input in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, raw-input

I've seen this code here

```
import time

start = time.time()
in_str = raw_input("Enter the thing:")
end = time.time()
elapsed = end-start
print "That took you " + str(elapsed) + " seconds. Man, you're slow."
```

and I want it so that if elapsed < 10 it prints Man, you're fast instead of slow. I've tried doing this with

if elapsed > 10 then print "" and if str(elspsed) > str(10): then do this but none of them see to work

Comment: Can you post *exactly* what you tried, even if it did not work? Then we can tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

start = time.time()
in_str = raw_input("Enter the thing:")
end = time.time()
elapsed = end - start

if elapsed > 10:
    print "That took you " + str(elapsed) + " seconds. Man, you're slow."
else:
    print "You are fast! " + str(elapsed)
```